# Rows without repeating records

Tags: sql, database

```
id     | name 
-------+------------------------------------- 
209096 | Pharmacy 
204200 | Eyecare Center 
185718 | Duffy PC 
214519 | Shopko 
162225 | Edward Jones 
7609   | Back In Action Chiropractic Center
```

I use `select id, name from customer order by random()`

There are 6 records i just want that when ever i query, i will get a unique row each time for six times and then it starts again from first or the records are ordered each time that the top one did't repeat

Comment: You want to select all possible orderings of the 6? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: If I follow, what you want to do is essentially form a random list of all of the records and, each query, get the next 6 items from that list until it's exhausted, then start again from the beginning.  Is that right?

Comment: If so, I would suggest using a hashing function, and order by MD5(CONCAT('somesalt', id, name)).  The sort won't be exactly random, but it will be close enough for most purposes, and that way you can use LIMIT/OFFSET.  (You should mention what database - MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc. - you are using in your question.)

Comment: The question looks like, there are only 6 records.
A query is fired 6 times. The query should return one row at a time. Each time the row selected should be randomly one of the 6 rows thats not selected in previous executions.

The 7th time the query is fired, it would obviously repeat one of the rows.

Comment: Yes that's what i want 
A query is fired 6 times
The query should return one row at a time
Each time the row selected should be randomly one of the 6 rows thats not selected in previous executions
The 7th time the query is fired, it would obviously repeat one of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you 6 random rows each time. The Group By is to ensure unique rows if your id is not a unique primary key, so maybe not needed - depending on your table structure.

```
SELECT TOP 6 id, name, ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS [RandomNumber]
FROM customer
GROUP BY id,name
ORDER BY [RandomNumber]
```

**Edit**: Sorry! Didn't read the question properly. Although you can use this to get a random row each time :)

If you want to specifically get all 6 rows in a random order 1 at a time you will need to store the order somewhere. Suggest creating a temp table and selecting from there, or if you are using a front end webpage get all 6 rows and store in a dataset.

Comment: Got your point. I wounder if i could handle this through sql rather then making a temp table and doing some coding stuff.

Comment: There is ALWAYS a way, not necessarily the best :) Check out my new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use that logic,
"milisecond" part of current date is always changing. We have a id column as numeric. So we can use modular function to get randomized order:

```
create table #data(id numeric(10), name varchar(20))
insert #data select 209096 , 'Pharmacy'
insert #data select 204200 , 'Eyecare Center'
insert #data select 185718 , 'Duffy PC'
insert #data select 214519 , 'Shopko'
insert #data select 162225 , 'Edward Jones'
insert #data select 7609   , 'Back In Action Chiropractic Center'

select * from #data order by id % (datepart(ms, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Maybe there is another way to do it just in SQL. Add a new BIT column "selected". Definitely not the fastest/best performance way to do it.

```
DECLARE @id INT
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM customer WHERE selected = 0)
BEGIN
   UPDATE customer SET selected = 0
END

SELECT @id = id FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 id, ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS [RandomNumber]
FROM customer WHERE selected = 0
ORDER BY [RandomNumber]) a

UPDATE customer SET selected = 1 WHERE id = @id
SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = @id
```